# TextBlock HyperLink and Anchor?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, anchor, textblock

I have a simple TextBlock like this (it has to be a TextBlock):

```
<ScrollViewer Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink TargetName="TestAnchor">Test</Hyperlink><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <TextBlock Text="Line" /><LineBreak />
    <Hyperlink Name="TestAnchor" />
</TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

What I would like to do is when the user clicks the HyperLink on top, that it will scroll down the Anchor on the bottom. Is this even possible in WPF?

Thanks!

Comment: Anchor, like in HTML (not Windows Forms)? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110.aspx) method which should scroll your scrollViewer to the `FrameworkElement` on which you invoked `BringIntoView`. The next step is to match clicked hyperlink with target hyperlink. Most straightforward approach would be using a `Dictionary`. And last step would be to handle `Hyperlink.Click` event.

Code behind:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Hyperlink,FrameworkElement> HyperlinkTargets = 
                    new Dictionary<Hyperlink,FrameworkElement>();

public Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HyperlinkTargets.Add(TestHyperlink, TestAnchor);
}

// this event handler should be attached to hyperlinks which will be used for navigation
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedHyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
    var targetHyperlink = HyperlinkTargets[clickedHyperlink];
    targetHyperlink.BringIntoView();
}
```

This is basically an implementation of *H.B.'s* idea from his comment.

---

Another solution which just come to my mind. If you want to move more code into XAML you can create a command which will navigate to element passed as parameter. Here is a command class:

```
class NavigateToCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement)parameter).BringIntoView();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter is FrameworkElement;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

And you can use it in your sample like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<ScrollViewer.Resources>
     <local:NavigateToCommand x:Key="navigateToCommand" />
</ScrollViewer.Resources>
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{StaticResource navigateToCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestAnchor}">Test</Hyperlink><LineBreak />
    /* TextBlocks */
    <Hyperlink Name="TestAnchor" />
</TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This will allow you to have everything (except new `ICommand` class) in XAML

Comment: Unless someone comes with a XAML-only solution, this will be the direction I'll head in. Thanks!

Comment: @SaphuA, added another solution which has more XAML and less code-behind

Comment: Using a command like that is quite a nice solution; i think you could improve it a bit though by implementing a proper CanExecute, e.g. return false if the `parameter` is currently `null` which could happen if the binding is quite dynamic, e.g. to the `SelectedItem` of some list control.

Answer (score 0):

[`TargetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.targetname.aspx) only works for windows and frames according to MSDN, so this is not possible.

Comment: Any substitute for TargetName would be fine too ;) I only copied TargetName from my testcode, it's the method I'm interested it.

Comment: I do not know of any substitute, if all fails you can handle the click event, find the target element by name, and call some scroll-into-view method on the scroll viewer.